# Hadoop2 client on Windows for a Linux Cluster

Tags: client, hadoop2

We have a linux hadoop cluster but for a variety of reasons have some windows clients connecting and pushing data to the linux cluster.
In hadoop1 we had been able to run hadoop via cygwin
However in hadoop2 as stated on the [website](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows) cygwin is not required or not supported.

Questions

1. what exactly has changed ? why would a client (only) not run under
   cygwin or it could ? Apart from paths what other considerations are at play ?
2. Apart from the property below for job submissions is there anything else that needs to considered for windows/client interacting with a linux cluster

   `conf.set("mapreduce.app-submission.cross-platform", "true");`
3. Extracting the hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.5.2 and running it from cygwin with the right configurations under $HADOOP_HOME/etc yields some classpath or classpath formation issues class not found issues ? For instance the following run

   ```
   hdfs dfs -ls
   Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell
   ```

Then looking at the classpath looks like they contain cygwin paths . attempt to convert them to windows paths so that the jar can be looked up

```
in $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hdfs.sh locate the dfs command and change to 
      elif [ "$COMMAND" = "dfs" ] ; then
      if $cygwin; then
         CLASSPATH=`cygpath -p -w "$CLASSPATH"`
      fi
      CLASS=org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell
```

This results in the following:

```
16/04/07 16:01:05 ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
    java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:378)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:393)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:386)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.preProcessForWindows(GenericOptionsParser.java:438)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:484)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:64)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:362)
    16/04/07 16:01:13 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    Warning: fs.defaultFs is not set when running "ls" command.
    Found 15 items
    -ls: Fatal internal error
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:505)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:478)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:738)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:831)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:814)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1100)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:582)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getOwner(RawLocalFileSystem.java:565)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Ls.adjustColumnWidths(Ls.java:139)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Ls.processPaths(Ls.java:110)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.recursePath(Command.java:373)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Ls.processPathArgument(Ls.java:98)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArgument(Command.java:271)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArguments(Command.java:255)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.FsCommand.processRawArguments(FsCommand.java:118)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:165)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:305)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:362)
```

For the above my question should I be going further to try and fix this so that i can reuse my existing client .sh scripts or just convert them .bat ?

Comment: converting the client .sh to .bat is becoming a nightmare with all the restrictions related to lengths of commands ; classpath etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that cygwin needs to return windows paths rather than cygwin paths. Also [winutils.exe](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/hdp-win-alpha/winutils.exe) needs to be installed in the path as described [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/wiki/Using-a-Windows-client-together-with-a-Linux-cluster)

Simply fix the scripts to return the actual win paths and turn off a few commands which don't run under cygwin

```
#!/bin/bash
# fix $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs
sed -i -e "s/bin=/#bin=/g" $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs
sed -i -e "s#DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR=\"\$bin\"/../libexec#DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR=\"\$HADOOP_HOME\\\libexec\"#g" $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs
sed -i "/export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH/i CLASSPATH=\`cygpath -p -w \"\$CLASSPATH\"\`" $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs

# fix $HADOOP_HOME/libexec/hdfs-config.sh
sed -i -e "s/bin=/#bin=/g" $HADOOP_HOME/libexec/hdfs-config.sh
sed -i -e "s#DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR=\"\$bin\"/../libexec#DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR=\"\$HADOOP_HOME\\\libexec\"#g" $HADOOP_HOME/libexec/hdfs-config.sh

# fix $HADOOP_HOME/libexec/hadoop-config.sh
sed -i "/HADOOP_DEFAULT_PREFIX=/a HADOOP_PREFIX=" $HADOOP_HOME/libexec/hadoop-config.sh
sed -i "/export HADOOP_PREFIX/i HADOOP_PREFIX=\`cygpath -p -w \"\$HADOOP_PREFIX\"\`" $HADOOP_HOME/libexec/hadoop-config.sh

# fix $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop 
sed -i -e "s/bin=/#bin=/g" $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop 
sed -i -e "s#DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR=\"\$bin\"/../libexec#DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR=\"\$HADOOP_HOME\\\libexec\"#g" $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop 
sed -i "/export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH/i CLASSPATH=\`cygpath -p -w \"\$CLASSPATH\"\`" $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop
```